# Button click methods

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to get my webform to check for empty textboxes, then validate it, submit to the database and then print it.. but I can't seem to figure out how to connect the methods to make it all work one after another once I click on the submit button. I have the code that checks it, then reports/validates it, but i need to connect another method (button1_click() which is a protected void on the default.aspx.cs page) first right before the print function..How would I connect it all together to work one after another?

```
function submitForm() {

    if (document.getElementById("hawbtxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the HAWB (B/L)!");
        return;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("invrefpotxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the INV/REF/PO!");
        return;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("hppartnumtxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the HP PART NUM!");
        return;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("iecpartnumtxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the IEC PART NUM!");
        return;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("qtytxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the QUANTITY!");
        return;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("bulkstxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the BULKS!");
        return;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("boxplttxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the BOX/PLT!");
        return;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("rcvddatetxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the DATE!");
        return;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("statustxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the STATUS!");
        return;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("carriertxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the CARRIER!");
        return;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("shippertxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the SHIPPER!");
        return;
    }

    //report   

    report = ""
    report += "ID: " + document.getElementById("generateidtxt").value + "<br>" //generated id
    report += "HAWB (B/L): " + document.getElementById("hawbtxt").value + "<br>"
    report += "INV/REF/PO: " + document.getElementById("invrefpotxt").value + "<br>"
    report += "HP PART NUM: " + document.getElementById("hppartnumtxt").value + "<br>"
    report += "IEC PART NUM: " + document.getElementById("iecpartnumtxt").value + "<br>"
    report += "QTY: " + document.getElementById("qtytxt").value + "<br>"
    report += "BULKS: " + document.getElementById("bulkstxt").value + "<br>"
    report += "BOX/PLT: " + document.getElementById("boxplttxt").value + "<br>"
    report += "RCVD DATE: " + document.getElementById("rcvddatetxt").value + "<br>"
    report += "STATUS: " + document.getElementById("statustxt").value + "<br>"
    report += "CARRIER: " + document.getElementById("carriertxt").value + "<br>"
    report += "SHIPPER: " + document.getElementById("shippertxt").value + "<p>"

    document.open();
    document.clear();
    document.write(report);
    document.close();


    //print

    if (confirm('Print Label?')) {
     //code for button1_click?  
        window.print();
    } else {
        form1.reset();
    }

}
```

This below is from the default.aspx.cs page

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);




    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into John_IEP_Crossing_Dock_Shipment values('" + generateidtxt.Text + "','" + hawbtxt.Text + "','" + invrefpotxt.Text + "','" + hppartnumtxt.Text + "','" + iecpartnumtxt.Text + "','" + qtytxt.Text + "','" + bulkstxt.Text + "','" + boxplttxt.Text + "','" + rcvddatetxt.Text + "','" + statustxt.Text + "','" + carriertxt.Text + "','" + shippertxt.Text + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
       // Label1.Visible = true;
       // Label1.Text = "Your DATA stored Successfully!";
        generateidtxt.Text = "";
        hawbtxt.Text = "";
        invrefpotxt.Text = "";
        hppartnumtxt.Text = "";
        iecpartnumtxt.Text = "";
        qtytxt.Text = "";
        bulkstxt.Text = "";
        boxplttxt.Text = "";
        rcvddatetxt.Text = "";
        statustxt.Text = "";
        carriertxt.Text = "";
        shippertxt.Text = "";
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason not use ***RequiredFieldValidator control*** and ***parameterized query***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do what you want in your current setup is to use an ajax call that will simulate a postback to the page due to button click. Why do you need to insert a record into a database table before and not after `window.print()`?

As a side-note: 
- you should add `Page_Unload` method to your webform with `con.Dispose();` in it;
- the insert query should be parameterized.

**Update:**

If `Button1` is a `Button` server control, it should submit the page to the server, and if `Button1_Click` is wired as button's OnClick event it should fire. To invoke javascript function `submitForm` on form submission, add attribute `onsubmit="submitForm()"` to the form tag in your page markup. Also, use `return false;` instead of `return;` inside `submitForm` to prevent form submission in case of failed validation.

Comment: Could you set me in the right direction on how to do the ajax call? The print function is not complete yet. It could go either way but I rather it be entered into the database before it prints.

Comment: Well since the print function isn't really needed at the moment I would really like just the submitForm() function to run and then the button1_click() to run directly right after it. All after the button is pushed.

Comment: If `Button1` is a `Button` server control, it should submit the page to the server, and if `Button1_Click` is wired as button's OnClick event it should fire. To invoke `submitForm` on form submission, add attribute `onsubmit="submitForm()"` to the form tag in your page markup. Also, use `return false;` instead of `return;` inside `submitForm` to prevent form submission in case of failed validation.

Comment: it says onsubmit is not a valid attribute of element 'button'

Comment: when i use OnClientClick = "javascript:submitForm();return false" it'll run the submit form when i click on the button and when i use onclick = "button1_click" alone it will submit into the database.. but I can't have both in the form tag or the submitform() will override and the button1_click will not run

Comment: `<form ... onsubmit="submitForm()"> ... </form>`

Comment: Okay I put the submitForm into the form tag. Now both seem to be doing what it needs to do. But the submitForm, once one of the alerts show up and i click okay, the form submits anyways and everything resets..

Comment: You did not change `return;` to `return false;` after your validation `alert`s, did you?

Comment: Not sure if this is the right way to do it but i put onsubmit="return submitForm() and it fixed the problem. so now the alerts work like it should.. but there is another problem now when I push on submit it will show the report for a split second before returning back to the original page.

Comment: I don't know what "it will show the report" means. But the page will postback and reload if you do not return `false` from the `onsubmit` javascript handler.

Comment: Okay, I had to figure out an alternative. Thanks for your help!